# Are these two ways of getting the filepath equivalent?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, directory, filepath, documents

```
NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
return [[pathArray objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
```

and

```
return [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];
```

the file is stored in my documents folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are not. The former returns a path to the file named data.plist in the app's Documents directory, the latter returns a path to the file named data.plist in the app's bundle, where all the app's resources, executable, etc are located.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains) for `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`

> Creates a list of path strings for the
>   specified directories in the specified
>   domains. The list is in the order in
>   which you should search the
>   directories. If expandTilde is YES,
>   tildes are expanded as described in
>   stringByExpandingTildeInPath.

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for the `NSBundle` method `pathForResource:ofType:`

> The method first looks for a matching
>   resource file in the non-localized
>   resource directory of the specified
>   bundle. (In Mac OS X, this directory
>   is typically called Resources but in
>   iOS, it is the main bundle directory.)
>   If a matching resource file is not
>   found, it then looks in the top level
>   of any available language-specific
>   “.lproj” directories. (The search
>   order for the language-specific
>   directories corresponds to the user’s
>   preferences.) It does not recurse
>   through other subdirectories at any of
>   these locations.

Therefore the former looks for files in a directory, and the latter looks in the bundle. These may not coincide.